# How to pronunce "agüero" perfectly

Tags: pronunciación

I have a question regarding how to pronounce the word *agüero*, or in general *güe*.
What is the right way to pronounce this word? Do native Spanish speakers pronounce "oo" and "eh" separately?

Comment: Have you tried listening to a recording online?  E.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBh7iI1a2dI.  Tell us what you're having trouble with so we can give you targeted assistance.

Comment: aparente001  yeah I have listened to multiple sources, dictionary, argentine, mexican, spanish sports videos but for me the difference is subtle. I have a friend who claims that the word agüero must be pronounced lie "gweh". He claims this is a three-syallble word. I wonder agüero is three or four -syllable word.

Comment: As Pablo pointed out, there's more than one right way to pronounce it.  Some Spanish learners have trouble learning the thing Pablo calls a fricative.  In that case I would much rather hear [a'wero] than a hard G sound (like the G in `game`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a friend who claims that [the *güe* in] the word *agüero* must be pronounced lie "gweh". He claims this is a three-syallble word.

Your friend is right :) The diaeresis (two dots) in `üe` just means that the U should be pronounced normally, like `ue`. And `ue` is a dyphtong, so `güe` is just one syllable: `a-güe-ro`.

And yes, `gweh` is pretty close to how it should be pronounced.

Comment: With `gweh`, are you talking about the second syllable?

Comment: I would note that the *g* in *agüero*, being placed between vowels, should be pronounced as a fricative. For some people, a weak [ɣ] before [w] reduces almost to nothing and *agüero* becomes [a'wero].